# non-filled nodes in networkX

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to have a node which is not filled, I mean there just should be its frame, contour. 
There are many options on the method

```
draw_networkx
```

but could not find this

Answer (score 2):

In [`draw_networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html), you could set the parameter `node_color` to `'none'`:

```python
nx.draw_networkx(G, node_color='none')
```

This will result in transparent nodes, but edges going to/from transparent nodes will be visible inside the node. I find this kind of ugly, but I haven't found a good solution for getting around this issue.

Comment: Well, I used alpha value for transparency, which ranges between 0-1. I am not sure if it possible to do what I want with networkX, transparency could be enough, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but the solution proposed does not fully address the original question. Those who want to have a transparent node with a frame can use the following code snippet.

```
#graph and positions are the user input / parameters
nx.draw_networkx(graph, positions, node_color = 'none')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, positions, linewidths= 0.5, edgecolors = 'red', node_color = 'none')
```

With the `linewidths` argument, you can set the thickness of the node frame and `edgecolors`  corresponds to the color of the node frame. It is also important to keep `node_color = 'none'` argument in both methods.